# OpenGL ES only draws a single triangle

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I have written code for 2 triangles to be drawn from 4 vertices using indices:

```
  GLES20.glUseProgram ( shader );

  GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray ( posLoc );
  GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer ( posLoc , 3 , GLES20.GL_FLOAT , false , 12 , field.verticesBuffer );
  //GLES20.glDrawElements ( GL10.GL_TRIANGLES , 3 , GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT , field.indicesBuffer );
  GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, field.vertices.length/3);
  GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray ( posLoc );

  GLES20.glUseProgram ( 0 );
```

This is called once per draw. I have tried both `glDrawArrays` as well as `glDrawElements` to no avail. My vertices and indices are defined as follows:

```
public static class Field
{
  private final int  BYTES_PER_FLOAT   = 4;
  private final int  BYTES_PER_SHORT   = 2;

  public float       vertices [ ]      = {

                                       - 0.5f , + 0.5f , + 0.0f , // top
                                                                  // left
                                       - 0.5f , - 0.5f , + 0.0f , // bottom
                                                                  // left
                                       + 0.5f , - 0.5f , + 0.0f , // bottom
                                                                  // right
                                       + 0.5f , + 0.5f , + 0.0f , // top
                                                                  // right
                                       };

  public short       indices [ ]       = { 0 , 1 , 2 , 3, 0, 2 };

  public FloatBuffer verticesBuffer    = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect ( vertices.length * BYTES_PER_FLOAT ).order ( ByteOrder.nativeOrder ( ) ).asFloatBuffer ( );
  public ShortBuffer indicesBuffer     = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect ( indices.length * BYTES_PER_SHORT ).order ( ByteOrder.nativeOrder ( ) ).asShortBuffer ( );

  public Field ( )
  {
     verticesBuffer.put ( vertices ).position ( 0 );
     indicesBuffer.put ( indices ).position ( 0 );
  }
}
```

For the most part the code is exactly the same as off of [Android's developer site](http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/draw.html). I have been scratching my head on this problem for quite some time now and would really like to understand why the code doesn't work. I have a bit of regular OpenGL background but am really new to OpenGL ES. If you need to see my shader code or any other code please ask.

Comment: Just to clarify, the title mentions one triangle is shown, but you never refer back to this in the question. Do you see one triangle? Which one?

Comment: @ci_ the only triangle show would be the first with indices of `(0, 1, 2)`

Comment: Your code looks a bit mixed up, can you show just one version you tried? Like in the glDrawElements method you have a hardcoded 3 for count, so this won't work (I know it's commented out now). But if you use the glDrawArrays version you can't use field.indices.length, because field.indices isn't used in that case. It's all a bit confusing.

Comment: @ci_ the hard-coded `3` I believe means that there are 3 coordinates per vertex, though I could be wrong,  while you are correct that I flubbed up on the `glDrawArrays` part

Comment: No, the 3 in glVertexAttribPointer means just that, but in glDrawElements  it means something else.

Comment: @ci_ I replaced `field.indices.length` with `field.vertices.length/3` and the issue remains

Comment: Actually I believe that may be all that's wrong, go with the glDrawElements   and use field.indices.length instead of the hardcoded 3.

Comment: The issue with the glDrawArrays version is also that you don't have enough vertices in `vertices []`, since you have no drawlist in this case, you have to duplicate shared vertices.

Comment: @ci_ thank you that worked I completely overlooked that feel free to make that an answer and I will accept it

Comment: @ci_ I had at some point messed up the `int count` paramter to `glDrawElements` and that was the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `glDrawElements` version you tried but replace the hardcoded `3` with the actual drawlist length.

```
GLES20.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, field.indices.length, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, field.indicesBuffer);
```

That parameter is the count of elements to be drawn.